# How is the color for the upvote count on comments calculated?

Tags: discussion, comment-voting

I just [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533297/color-coding-based-on-number/5533342#5533342) in which the OP basically wants a mathematical model for doing interpolation between color points *in a way which would look natural to the human eye* (and which presumably is not what linear interpolation would produce).

My answer was to pre-pick N colors and simply project from the initial input range to these color bands.

Which led me to wonder... how is it done here on SO?

Comment: Can you point to a post that has comments with upvote counts in different colors?

Comment: @Gabe: The highest voted question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books) has some variety.

Comment: I see. The styles are "cool", "warm", "hot", and "supernova".

Comment: Translate RGB to the HSL color space.  Different S.  It's a bit off, they probably picked them from a table.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

css

```
.supernova {
color: #FE7A15 !important;
}

.hot {
color: #CF7721 !important;
}

.warm {
color: #9B764F !important;
}

.cool {
color: #999 !important;
}
```

js

```
// e.g. options = { min: 15, max: 300, setIsValid: function }

var max = options.max;

var css = cur > max * 0.8 ? "supernova" : cur > max * 0.6 ? "hot" : cur > max * 0.4 ? "warm" : "cool";
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to dig.

Comment: I love the shorthand if statements in the last line.