# Benefit Of "this is a great Comment"

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do “great comment” votes do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/960/what-do-great-comment-votes-do)

How exactly any one get any benefit by an upvoted (this is a great comment) comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get a badge if you receive enough comment upvotes. Additionally there is a nice glowing up-arrow displayed next to *your* comment if it has upvotes.

Comment: Funnily nice answer :)